# Shift a column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose that I have a dataframe like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
```

And I would like to shift a column, adding a column like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     y shifted_x
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     4        NA
2     2     5         1
3     3     6         2
```

Basically, I want to work with timeseries, so I would like to get previous values and use them as feature. In `python` I know I can do:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    df[f'feature_{i}']=df['sepal_length'].shift(i)
```

Where `df` is a `pandas` Dataframe.
Any equivalent code for doing this in `R`?

Comment: There is `lag` in `dplyr` `df <- df %>% mutate(shifted_x = lag(x))` or `shift` from ` data.table` `setDT(df)[, shifted_x := shift(x)]`

Comment: In python you do not use a for loop. `df['shifted_x'] = df.sepal_length.shift()` works perfectly. In R, look at the answer osted below.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent in `R` `tidyverse` is `dplyr::lag`.  Create the column in `mutate` and update the object by assigning (`<-`) back to the same object 'df'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(shifted_x = lag(x))
```

or if we need to use the `shift`, there is `shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, shifted_x := shift(x)]
```

Also, if we need to create more than one column, `shift` can take a vector of values in `n`

```
setDT(df)[, paste0('shifted', 1:3) := shift(x, n = 1:3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the `flag` function from the `collapse` package.

```
library(collapse)

df %>%
  ftransform(shifted_x = flag(x))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#       x     y shifted_x
# * <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1     4        NA
# 2     2     5         1
# 3     3     6         2
```